# Select next row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-express

I would like to concatenate two text fields from the current row with the same field from the next row

So if the table is like

```
field1  field2  field3

text1    text3  order1
text2    text4  order1
```

i would like to do this:

```
if (field3.current_row = field3.next_row)
     SELECT field1 + getNextRow(field1) as "Concatenated Field" FROM table
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You need some way to identify the *current record* and the *next record*. If you can't define the criteria for finding those records, this question can't be answered.

Comment: You may be able to do it using row_number and a triangular join. Please see the following link http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic483631-338-1.aspx

Comment: Do you have an ID column in the table or just field1 and field2?

Comment: @Yuck, if the ordernumber is the same in both rows, then i want to concatenate.

Comment: @Dan P, i do have an ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something similar to this:

```
create table #temp
(
    field1 varchar(50),
    field2 varchar(50)
)

insert into #temp values ('text1', 'text3')
insert into #temp values ('text2', 'text4')

;with cte as
(
    select *, row_number()over(order by field1) as rownum
    from #temp
)
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    select c1.field1 + ' ' + (SELECT field1 FROM cte c2 WHERE c2.rownum = c1.rownum + 1) as ConcField
    from cte c1
) c
where c.concfield is not null

drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are already on SQL Server **2012**, you can do the following:

```
SELECT field1 + lead(field1) over (order by field1) as "Concatenated Field"
from table
```